# How to replace javascript file in some condition on pageload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a script that replaces original javascript file in some conditions.
When I ran the code(link inside) itself, it worked fine.
But it doesn't work when i uploaded the js file and appended it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://agar.ddack.oa.gg/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
if (window.top === window.self) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://yourjavascript.com/2020170916/botcore.js';
    $("body").append(script);

} else {
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work..
It seems that it doesn't work on pageload and I have no idea to make this work.
please help my noob question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write` to get your script to run immediately.

```
if (window.top === window.self) {    
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript src="http://yourjavascript.com/2020170916/botcore.js"></script>'    
}
```

Comment: What I want to replace is one specific js code which is // @webRequest   [{"selector":"/core.js","action":"cancel"}]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EOsAfT8   here is the page script and I want to replace core.js